# how to pass by reference in javascript

Tags: javascript

How should I pass by reference in a JavaScript function?

For example:

```
function passByReference(a){
    a = "banana";
}

var x = "apple";
passByReference(x);
```

Here x should output `banana`.

I am new to JavaScript; any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass by reference. If you want to modify the state of your caller from within the called function, there are two ways you could do:

Sometimes it fits best to wrap the state in an object:

```
var x = { valueToChange: 'initialValue' };
passByReference(x);
```

This works because with objects, a pointer to the address where the object lies is passed. That pointer is passed by value but it still points to the same object.

In some other cases a callback does the trick:

```
var x = "apple";

passByReference(function (newValue) { x = newValue; });

function passByReference(callback) {
    callback("banana");
}
```

This works because if you define a function as above it builds a *closure* together with all variables it references. When your function gets called it really modifies the value of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the variable with an object. Properties of objects are passed by reference.

```
function passByReference(a) {
   a.fruit = 'banana';
}

var wrapper = {fruit: 'apple'};
passByReference(wrapper);
```

Comment: Not exactly. Objects are also passed by value. However the properties are references itself. For example: This would not work `a={fruit: 'banana'}` inside the function

Comment: yeah @zhonk you are right properties are references itself and objects are also passed by value.